# How to convert unix timestamp to date with time zone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, timezone

How can I convert for example timestamp:

```
1559347196759
```

to datetime with time zone 'GMT+2' using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this does what you want:

```
select (timestamp 'epoch' + 1559347196759 * interval '1 millisecond') at time zone '+02:00'
```

The first expression converts the value to UTC.  The second shifts the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a `timestamp with time zone` (absolute time) and convert it to the appropriate time zone:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1559347196759 / 1000.0) AT TIME ZONE '-02';

        timezone         
-------------------------
 2019-06-01 01:59:56.759
(1 row)
```